# A polynomial specialized at (1, 1, ..., 1)

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, contest-math

Consider the polynomial
\begin{eqnarray}
P_{l, p}(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_{2n+1})=\sum_{j=0}^{2n+1}(-1)^j\sum_{\stackrel{0\leq k_r\leq l-1}{k_1+\cdots+k_{2n+1}=lj-p}}\lambda_1^{k_1}\cdots\lambda_{2n+1}^{k_{2n+1}}
\end{eqnarray}
What is $P_{l, p}(1, 1, \cdots, 1)$?